# Multithreaded Message Game

Tags: java, multithreading

Use cases Messaging app between two users.

GameMain is for multithreading application refers to SendMessageWrokers.java

Only 2 user need to be defined and message app needs to finalize after a restriced amount of message count.

GameMain.java

```
package org.nb;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class GameMain{

    public final static int MESSAGE_LIMIT = 10;
    Player initiator = new Player(0,"Initiator",true);
    Player player = new Player(1,"Receiver");
    SendMessageWorker messageWorker;

    public GameMain(){
        Player[] players =new Player[2];
        players[0] = initiator;
        players[1] = player;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameMain gameMain = new GameMain();
        gameMain.startGame();
    }

    public void startGame(){

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Shutdown Hook is running, Application Terminating")));

        Integer counter = 0;

        BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

        ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, blockingQueue);

        while (true) {
            counter++;
            messageWorker =  new SendMessageWorker(counter.toString(),"Sending a new message ",initiator,player);
            executorService.submit(messageWorker);
            if (counter >= MESSAGE_LIMIT) {
                break;
            }
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

        Conversation conversation = initiator.getConversationHashMap(player.getId());

        List<Message> messageList = conversation.getConversation();

        for(Message message : messageList){
            System.out.println("Message : " + message.getContent() + " - Date :" + message.getDate() +
                    "- Sender " + message.getSender().getName() +  "- Receiver " + message.getReceiver().getName() );
        }

        System.out.println("Application Terminating ...");
    }

}
```

Conversation.java

```
package org.nb;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Conversation {

    private Player participants[];

    private ArrayList<Message> conversation = new ArrayList<>();

    public Conversation(Player player1 , Player player2){
        participants = new Player[2];
        this.participants[0] = player1;
        this.participants[1] = player2;
    }

    void addMessage(Message message){
        conversation.add(message);
    }

    public ArrayList<Message> getConversation() {
        return conversation;
    }

}
```

Message.java

```
package org.nb;

import java.util.Date;

public class Message {

    private String content;
    private Player sender;
    private Player receiver;
    private Date date;
    private Boolean ack = false;

    public Message(String content, Player player, Player toPlayer) {
        this.content = content;
        this.sender = player;
        this.receiver = toPlayer;
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    public Message(String content, Player player, Player toPlayer,Boolean ack) {
        this.content = content;
        this.sender = player;
        this.receiver = toPlayer;
        this.date = new Date();
        this.ack = ack;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public Player getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public Player getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

}
```

Player.java

```
package org.nb;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Player {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean initiator = false;

    private HashMap<Integer,Conversation> conversationHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Player(int id,String name, boolean initiator){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.initiator=initiator;
    }

    public Player(int id, String name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isInitiator() {
        return initiator;
    }

    public Conversation getConversationHashMap(int id) {
        return conversationHashMap.get(id);
    }

    public void setConversationHashMap(Integer playerId, Conversation  conversation) {
        this.conversationHashMap.put(playerId, conversation);
    }

}
```

SendWorkerMessage.java

```
package org.nb;

public class SendMessageWorker implements Runnable {

    private String name = "SendMessageTask";

    String content;
    Player initiator;
    Player receiver;

    private String counter;

    public SendMessageWorker (String counter,String content,Player initiator, Player receiver) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.content = content;
        this.initiator = initiator;
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

            if (initiator.isInitiator() == false) {
                System.out.println("Only initiator can send message");
                return;
            }

            Conversation conversation = initiator.getConversationHashMap(receiver.getId());
            if (conversation == null) {
                conversation = new Conversation(initiator, receiver);
            }

            Message message = new Message(content, initiator, receiver);
            conversation.addMessage(message);

            Message messageAck = new Message(content.concat(String.valueOf("_" + counter)), receiver, initiator, true);
            conversation.addMessage(messageAck);

            initiator.setConversationHashMap(receiver.getId(), conversation);
            receiver.setConversationHashMap(initiator.getId(), conversation);

    }

}
```

Comment: Note that this is one of these assignments where I'm missing information. The message number seems to appear out of nothing, and there is no indication on how the system needs to shutdown (which is kinda important if you have two *processes* specifically). Basically you need some kind of message that indicates the shutdown to happen. Over.

Comment: I was looking for a better method manage gracefully shutdown. I have added shutDownHook and counter limit. Do you recommend to changing  message context itself ?

Answer (score 4):

### Design

The design is OK; it seems to use data classes and some classes that perform operations.

In true OO fashion, I would expect the player to send the message. For instance, you could do `Player.sendMessageTo(int otherPlayerID, String message)`. You could initialize the player with a `MessageHandler` that does the actual sending of the message. The player then can keep a list of conversations with other player(s). That way you can hide much of the technical details from the "game". Similarly, you can have a `Player.receiveAcknowledgement` that is triggered by the same `MessageHandler`.

### Code review

**GameMain**

```
public final static int MESSAGE_LIMIT = 10;
Player initiator...
```

I'd always separate the constant values and the fields using an empty line.

```
Player initiator = new Player(0,"Initiator",true);
```

This is why you don't use boolean parameters: it is completely unclear what `true` does here when browsing through the code. Instead, use an enum `PlayerType` with values `INITIATOR` and `RECEIVER`. Note that you could now do away with the name - unless you want to have multiple receivers.

A less intrusive refactor would be to use a constant `INITIATOR = true` to be used. This has the disadvantage that other developers overlook the constant though (for `Cipher.getInstance` in Java I keep seeing `Cipher.getInstance(1, ...)` instead of `Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE)`).

Consider maybe not numbering players, but using the name itself as ID (using a `HashMap<String, Player> nameToPlayer`, for instance). Generally you want to avoid having fields that have a similar function.

```
Integer counter = 0;
```

Always prefer basic types: `int counter = 0`. Auto-boxing will take care of the rest.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, blockingQueue);
```

Why 10, 1, 1 and 0L? You need to use well named constant values here.

```
messageWorker =  new SendMessageWorker(counter.toString(),"Sending a new message ",initiator,player);
```

I'd try and not stringify before it is necessary. Just use the `counter` as parameter. Don't forget your code style, and add spaces after the commas. Note that you can use `Integer.toString(int)` to convert; no need to box it.

```
if (counter >= MESSAGE_LIMIT) {
    break;
}
```

I've got nothing against `while (true) { ... if (condition) break ...}` *in principle* but why not just a `for` loop here?

```
Conversation conversation = initiator.getConversationHashMap(player.getId());
```

As reader I would expect to get a `HashMap` here, not a specific object. Furthermore, it is not clear to me what a "conversation hash map" **is**.

```
List<Message> messageList = conversation.getConversation();
```

Hmm, that's slightly weird, get a conversation from a conversation. `getMessages` maybe?

**Conversation**

I would expect a *list* of players. Try and avoid arrays, the are not very OO.

Then you would get:

```
public Conversation(Player ... players){
    participants = List.of(players);
}
```

and note that the actual constructor call is *not even changed*.

```
public ArrayList<Message> getConversation() {
    return conversation;
}
```

Try and avoid to expose the state of an object instance, you're failing to encapsulate the field. Return either an iterator or return `Collections.unmodifiableList(conversation)`.

**Message**

```
private Boolean ack = false;
```

`ack` will automatically be assigned `false`. `ack` is never read, and it is again an object instance rather than `boolean`.

`Date` should preferably not be used; try and use `Instant.now()` instead (and possibly also include a clock as parameter, for testing purposes).

```
public Conversation getConversationHashMap(int id) {
    return conversationHashMap.get(id);
}
```

You probably refactored this, but forgot to change the name of the method. `getConversationFromHashMap` would be better, but it would expose the inner workings of the class. `getConversationWithPlayer(int id)` is probably best.

Note that because `Conversation` is not immutable, the returned value again exposes state.

**SendMessageWorker**

```
if (initiator.isInitiator() == false) {
    System.out.println("Only initiator can send message");
    return;
}
```

**Never** keep running with invalid state. *Bad programmer*. Down (the application)!

If you should not get into such a state: `throw new IllegalStateException("Only initiator can send message")`.

```
if (conversation == null) {
    conversation = new Conversation(initiator, receiver);
}
```

Ugh, don't do this. Either use an empty conversation and intialize in the object, or - if that's too expensive - lazily instantiate a conversation.

Note that this is resolved if you let the user keep track of their own conversation(s). A good design will lead you into fewer traps.

Comment: As a first question. Do you recommend to "MessageHandler" as a Runnable Thread still? And initialize the Player ?

Comment: In my scheme I guess it makes more sense to control the players using a thread. The message handler can simply sync on the blocking queue. Hopefully, that will also make it easier to do something using two processes. I would introduce a different class for that though. What about "Puppeteer" ? ;)